# How do I display a list of objects in an Exception?

Tags: c#, list, exception

I'm passing a List of Custom Objects to my Custom Exception Class and need to display all the objects in the message. How can I do this?

```
public class MissingUnitSNSException : Exception
{
    public MissingUnitSNSException()
    {

    }

    public MissingUnitSNSException(List<UnitViewModel> missingsns)
        : base(String.Format("Serial Numbers not found: {0}", missingsns))
    {

    }
}
```

The error tells me the type of object, but I need the serial number attribute that's tied to each object in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about replacing `missingsns` with a string of comma separated serial numbers. Like so:

```
string.join(", ", missingsns.Select(sns => sns.SerialNumber.ToString()))
```

This should list out the serial numbers like: `A01, B01, C02, ...`

---

Full line:

```
public MissingUnitSNSException(List<UnitViewModel> missingsns)
        : base(String.Format("Serial Numbers not found: {0}", 
                  string.join(", ", missingsns.Select(sns => sns.SerialNumber.ToString()))))
```

Comment: I think this is the best possible answer without any information on how OP would like the message to be structured

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard Thanks! OP didn't provide format so I went with how I would format it. Commas are easy to read and a good way to show a list of numbers. For anyone else who didn't want commas, you can replace the `string.join` with whatever delimiter you want/need. Ex: `string.join("|", someList);`

Comment: That seemed to do it! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Please do not put important information into the message field. Getting them out there will be a pain for the user of your code!

Exceptions are classes. Add a readonly property for this data. Add it to what ToString() will return. This is one of the core rules of proper exception Handling:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Now with objects, you propably do not want to assign Reference to the Exception. Not only could the Exception keep the objects alive, there is a decent chance that Dispose is called on those instances before you get to process the Exception - making those references pretty useless.

As you seem content with "only" string data, a `string[]` might be a good type. You do have to mind to shallow clone it when handing it out, but otherwise it is normal readonly Property of Exceptions.

Comment: The message is supposed to be localizable, too (whether or not you localize yours is a different matter), so that's another reason not to put that information in the message.

Comment: @madreflection Indeed. It is explained in way more detail in the 2nd link.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for you to show the serial number attribute that's tied to each object in the list. you have to go into the list and select all Serial number attribute like so:

```
public class ExceptionClass: Exception   
{
      public ExceptionClass()
      {

      }
      public ExceptionClass(List<string> names) :base(String.Format("String with ID :{0} not found", string.Join(", ", names.Select(sns => sns.SerialNumber.ToString()))))
      {

      }


  }
```